# Setting a C++ Class char* in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

I am writing a simple client / server program to mess around with socket programming. I made two classes, one for the client and one for the server. I can run my server with no problems and also my client can connect. But now I am attempting to modify my client so it accepts the hostname and port number in the constructor.

Here is what I have so far (client.h class only the constructor and attributes):

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

class Client
{
    public:

    Client(char *in_hostname, int in_port)
        : hostname(&in_hostname), port(in_port)
    {

    }

    ~Client() {}



    private:

    char *hostname;
    int port;


};

#endif
```

I am having a hard time setting the `char * hostname` from the constructor. I am obviously having a little trouble with pointers and references. Can someone help me out here, coding mostly in PHP for the past 5 years has made my C++ rusty...

Here is the C++ file I use the client.h class.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "client.h"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    char * hostname;
    int port;

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        hostname = argv[1];
        port = argv[2];

        Client *client = new Client(hostname, port);


        delete(client);
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Usage: ./client hostname port" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing traditional C constructs (e.g. `char *` instead of `std::string`) with C++ code. This is not easy to do unless you already know C++ pretty well, and should be avoided if you do not have to interface with existing C code.

Comment: You can't convert a `char*` to an `int` just be assignment.  You're going to end up connecting to some random port which is the lower 16 bits of the address where `argv[2]` happens to point.

Comment: Why use `new` to allocate the Client? You delete it at the end of the scope anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to be coding in C++ may I suggest using std::string instead of char pointers?

```
class Client
{
    public:

    Client(const string& in_hostname, int in_port)
        : hostname(in_hostname), port(in_port)
    {

    }

    ~Client() {}

    private:

    std::string hostname;
    int port;
};
```

Edit:

In response to your comment.  If you have to pass the pointer around to another function you can get it from  std::string::c_str

```
std::string stuff;
stuff.c_str();
```

Comment: I am using char* because after i need to pass it into this function: getaddrinfo(const char*, ect..). I will try it with a string

Comment: You can get a `const char *` by calling `c_str()` on the `string`.

Comment: Thanks, i replaced the const char * with strings and now it will copy the hostname and port into my client class.

Answer (score 3):

> I am having a hard time setting the `char * hostname` from the constructer.

Change `&in_hostname` to `in_hostname`

```
Client(char *in_hostname, int in_port)
        : hostname(in_hostname), port(in_port)
    {

    }
```

However if you want your code to be **clean** you should use `std::string` (C++ style string) instead of (`char *`) i.e C style string

Comment: This type of shallow copy is going to end up causing problems for him in the long run. There's no way for the calling code to know that the Client object took possession of the char*, and there's no way for the Client object to know how the character buffer was allocated when it comes time to free it.  If he wants to use char* as the parameter, he needs to allocate a new buffer and copy the parameter into it.  That being said, as all the other comments have mentioned, this is a great place for a std::string.

Comment: Replace "clean" with "reliable"|"bug-free"|"maintainable".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Mahasiswa{
    public:  
      char nama[1000];
      double tinggi,berat,imb;
      Mahasiswa *next;

      Mahasiswa(char* nama,double tinggi,double berat){
            Mahasiswa::nama = nama;
            Mahasiswa::tinggi  = tinggi;
            Mahasiswa::berat   = berat;
      }
      double HasilBmi(){
            double tinggi_meter = tinggi / 100;
            imb = berat/(tinggi_meter*tinggi_meter);
            return imb;
      }
      char* Getname(char* nama){
      return nama;
    }

};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.